# The Kerr metric applied to a solid rotating body

Tags: general-relativity, potential, centripetal-force, angular-velocity, kerr-metric

Can the Kerr metric be used as an exterior solution to analyse the vacuum outside a rotating solid body or does it only apply to a rotating black hole? If it can't, is there an alternative exterior solution that can be used for a solid body? I note that the exterior Schwarzschild solution is identical to the black hole Schwarzschild metric for the vacuum outside the solid body.

If we can use the metric with a solid body, would the body be assumed to be an oblate spheroid rather an an ideal sphere and the inner boundary of the vacuum solution where it is valid (if it is) would be also be an oblate spheroid?

Would a surface of equal coordinate time define a sphere and would a surface of equal proper time (for ideal clocks that are stationary in the metric) define an oblate spheroid?

My motivation is to try and understand the effective potential on the surface of a real rotating solid gravitational body, which relates to some recent hot topics in this forum.

This website mentions effective potential which takes into account time dilation due to gravitational potential and due to orbital angular velocity in the analysis of [orbits in strongly curved spacetime](https://www.fourmilab.ch/gravitation/orbits/) and I am wondering if the concept is related to the Kerr metric. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kerr metric strictly only applies to the spacetime of a black hole with spin.

There are alternatives for the spacetime around axisymmetric rotating solid bodies. These are *approximate* solutions to the field equations based on a multipole expansion, parameterised with the mass and angular momentum (as per the Kerr metric) but then including higher order terms attributable to the mass quadrupole, spin octupole and mass hexadecapole (e.g., [Berti et al. 2005](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/358/3/923/1028039); [Pappas 2017](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/466/4/4381/2869876)).

Such metric approximations apply *outside* the rotating bodies.  The rotating bodies are not spherically symmetric - hence the mass quadrupole term etc.

There is also an approximate approach that provides a metric both inside and outside a rotating body that was developed by [Hartle & Thorne (1968)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1968ApJ...153..807H/abstract). This however does still assume that the body is spherically symmetric.

The metrics are often expressed in a more complex coordinate system than the simple Droste coordinates applied to Schwarzschild spacetime - an example is given in the Pappas (2017) paper.

On the last part of your question - the concept of an effective potential can be used in any spacetime, including the non-rotating Schwarzschild spacetime.